# Can I make `user` objectClass to inherit attributes from my custom `xyz` objectClass?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, samba4

#### TL;DR:

How can I make `user` objectClass in Active Directory to inherit the attributes from my custom `xyz` objectClass?

#### More text:

This seemed to be any easy task, but I I have been searching and trying for couple of hours with no success.

I have a simple fresh Active Directory Domain Controller, and all users has `user` objectClass.

Now when I create a custom attribute and add it to `user` objectClass, I find it every user's attributes (i.e. administrator will have this new custom attribute, user abc will have it, etc...).

But what I want to do is, creating my different objectClasses for each service, let's say, an objectClass for `OpenVPN` where all OpenVPN service attributes are organized. And then I want `user` objectClass to inherit all those attributes from `OpenVPN` objectClass.

I tried the following: In `user` objectClass property, in `relationship` tab, auxiliary classes, I added `OpenVPN` objectClass, but that did nothing. I don't know what does this relationship should do.

Could some body help me in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK that seems a little bit not related to the question, but I will share my experience, maybe that helps someone.

According to what I said:

> I tried the following: In user objectClass property, in relationship tab, auxiliary classes, I added OpenVPN objectClass, but that did nothing. I don't know what does this relationship should do.

**Actually that works!** That is pretty simply the method to do what I wanted.

The problem was, that doing refresh in Active Directory Users and Computers program doesn't show the new added attributes (even if AD was restarted). **Your LDAP browser (let's say AD Users and Computers) should be completely closed and reopened (not only refreshed)** to show the new added attributes.

Comment: This is the correct approach if you want to add multiple related attributes to an LDAP objectClass.